# Issue trying to use SQLException on hibernate commit processing

Tags: java, sqlexception

Hell.  I am trying to figure out a commit exception error when doing an update of a spring batch job.  I am working on adding SQL Exception to our commit processing in Hibernate because the regular Exception doesn't seem to be helpful.  Here is the code I currently have:

```
    if (editRollBackNeeded) {
        try {
            hibernateTransaction.setRollbackOnly();
            hibernateTransaction.rollback();
            returnCode = 16;
            logger.info(" ");
            logger.info("RECORD EDIT ERROR " + "ROLLBACK OCCURRED - INVESTIGATE");
            logger.info(" ");
            message = message + " " + System.lineSeparator() 
                              + "RECORD EDIT ERROR " + "ROLLBACK OCCURRED - INVESTIGATE " + System.lineSeparator();
            terminateProcess(returnCode, message)  ;   
        } catch (Exception rollbackE) {
            logger.info("ROLLBACK EXCEPTION " + rollbackE.getMessage() + " OCCURRED - INVESTIGATE");
            message = message + " " + System.lineSeparator() 
                              + "ROLLBACK EXCEPTION WAS " + rollbackE.getMessage() + System.lineSeparator() 
                              + " " + System.lineSeparator();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            hibernateTransaction.commit();
        } catch (SQLException commitExcep) { 
            commitExcep.printStackTrace(pw);  
            logger.info("COMMIT EXCEPTION WAS " + sw.toString());
            logger.debug("COMMIT LOCAL MESSAGE " + Arrays.asList(commitExcep.getLocalizedMessage()));
            logger.info(sw.toString()) ;
            message = message + " " + System.lineSeparator() 
                              + "COMMIT EXCEPTION WAS " + sw.toString() + System.lineSeparator() 
                               + " " + System.lineSeparator();
            if (hibernateTransaction != null) {
                try {
                    hibernateTransaction.rollback();
                    returnCode = 16;
                    logger.info("SQL ERROR " + "ROLLBACK OCCURRED - INVESTIGATE");
                    logger.info(" ");
                    message = message + " " + System.lineSeparator() 
                                      + "SQL ERROR " + "ROLLBACK OCCURRED - INVESTIGATE " + System.lineSeparator();
                } catch (Exception rollbackE) {
                    logger.info("ROLLBACK EXCEPTION " + rollbackE.getMessage() + " OCCURRED - INVESTIGATE");
                    returnCode = 16;
                    terminateProcess(returnCode, message)  ;

                }

            } else {
            }
        }
    }
```

This is located in the afterStep part of Spring batch.  I am throwing all of the Exceptions especially SQL Exception.  I am getting a compile error saying 'SQLExecution is never thrown in the body of corresponding try statement".  I don't really get this since I have this error.  Can you look and see what I am messing up in.

Thanks

Comment: What class is hibernateTransaction? It looks like its commit() method does not throw SQLException.

Comment: hibernateTransaction is coming from the Transaction class

Comment: Hybernate wraps all SQLExceptions in non checked Exceptions. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html

Answer (score 1):

Hibernates Transaction class method commit() throws HibernateException, not SQLException. So change your catch to HibernateException.

Comment: The issue is that I am trying to get the getNextException() so I can see what the SQL error on the commit is.  How do I pull this information or a version of that information without SQLException.   Thanks

Comment: You might be able to use getStackTrace and iterate through that, but I think you need to mention in your question what exactly you are trying to do and post the code you have tried.

Comment: @hammerva are you trying to get the root cause of the exception

Comment: Yes.   Maybe it isn't an SQLexecption to begin with and it is problem somewhere else.  I am assuming it is because my trace is showing org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not perform addBatch